# Function pointer to a struct function pointer

Tags: c, pointers, binary-tree

Today I received a homework, about `function pointer(binary tree)`.
There is a chunk of code that i can not understand... I understand what a `function pointer` is and how it work but what about 2 `function pointers` (1 is in a `parameter`)

header.h

```
typedef struct _node_ {
int key;
struct _node_ *left;
struct _node_ *right;
} node;

typedef struct _bstree_ {
node *root_node;
int (*compare_keys)(int x, int y);  //this code
} bstree;
```

c file

```
void bst_init_with_comp_operator(bstree *bst, int(*comp)(int x, int y)) {
bst_init(bst);

bst->compare_keys = comp; // what does this mean? a fucntion pointer parameter to function pointer to struct?

 }
```

// comp is supposed to return -1 if x should be treated as less than y,zero if x should enter code here` be treated as equal to y, or 1 if x should be treated as greater than y.

so I created this function:

```
int compare (int x , int y)
{
if(x < y) return -1;
else if(x == y) return 0;
else return 1;

}
```

main.c

```
bstree tree;
bst_init_with_comp_operator(&tree,compare(2,3))
```

but it doesnt work ...

normally we just need something like this

```
 int function(int x, int y)
 { return x+y;}

 int (*pointerf) (int , int)

 pointerf = function;

 pointerf(2,3)
```

Comment: Please define "it doesnt work". Does it compile or not? Does it run? Does it crash? Did it erase your hard drive?

Comment: it gives me this error: warning: passing argument 2 of bst_init_with_comp_operator makes pointer from interger without a cast

Comment: That is because you passed the result of "compare(2,3)" not the function which would be just "compare".

Comment: @Ouxi `compare(2,3)` in `bst_init_with_comp_operator(&tree,compare(2,3))` is call to the function `compare` with two argument `2` and `3`. `compare()` will get called and will return an integer which will be passed to `bst_init_with_comp_operator()`.

Comment: @Ouxi the correct statement is `bst_init_with_comp_operator(&tree,compare)`. This will pass the address of `compare()`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `bst_init_with_comp_operator(&tree,compare))`, this will pass a function adress as a parameter, while if you do `compare(a,b)` it pass a result of this function, so an integer 1, 0 or -1.